# Spacetime diagrams from Takeuchi's book

Tags: diagrams

Does anyone know if the spacetime diagrams appearing in Takeuchi's book on relativity were created using a dedicated LaTeX package?

Amazon has a preview of the book; the diagrams appear in chapter 3, though I would also be interested in the other drawings in the book.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Illustrated-Guide-Relativity-Tatsu-Takeuchi/dp/0521141001

Update:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My guess is that you will not get many answers, since it is unclear what the diagrams looks like. Your link is also not very helpful. Amazon doesn't show any pages of chapter 3, at least not to me. Have you found your diagrams in this preview?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you click on the book cover on amazon it should show a preview, including some pages from chapter 3 where the diagrams appear (that is the reason why I included the link in the question). See page 41 for instance. I'm not sure whether you need an amazon account to see the preview though.

Comment: Do you mean the ufo stuff?

Comment: Posting a scan, with proper attribution, should not be a copyright breach.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: I am curious about those too, but primarily inteested in the spacetime diagrams, i.e. horizontal space axis, vertical time axis, thin squared background grid, etc.

Comment: I can not see any chapter 3 though I have an amazon account. These ufo diagrams are too detailed to be done in LaTeX. It is possible to do this with tikz, but it is much more work than doing it in inkscape. So it is probably not done in LaTeX.

Comment: Do you mean diagrams like the one  on the bottom of the page https://archive.org/stream/AnIllustratedGuideRelativity/An%20Illustrated%20Guide%20Relativity#page/n48/mode/1up? If so, I doubt there's some dedicated package for this, but writing your own shouldn't too difficult (I'd use metapost, but with tikz it is surely also possible). The question is: how many of them do you need? If only a few, then, probably, it's easier to draw them by hand in, say, inkscape.

Comment: @SergeySlyusarev: Yes, I meant those ones. I see then, I suspected there might be something dedicated (such an extension of TikZ or something). Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @MaestroGlanz: Yes, I thought that might be the case with the pictures with ufos, cars, trees etc. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be very sure, that this hasn't been made with an external program like inkscape. Why?

Comment: Special thanks are due to T¯ oru Kawahara of Iwanami Shoten for his
enthusiasm in bringing this book to publication. Without his help in dig-
itizing my hand-drawn diagrams, and translating the characters’ words
in the drawings into Japanese, this book would never have been com-
pleted.